# WPF retaining IsFocused status for user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol(UC), and several of it's implementations on 1 screen. Now, whenever any of them has IsFocused property set to True(it will only stay true for 1 at a time), there are some style effects that will appear for only that specific implementation(some highlighting styles basically). If some other implementation gets focused upon, those styles will only appear for that new one, and will be lost for old one.

Now, on that screen, if I create a completely new button, which has nothing to do with those controls, and if I click on it, the styles are lost for the last focused UC. I want to retain the styles for the UCs specifically, so that, if a UC is already focused and showing the styles, those should stay as long as some other UC of that type is not clicked upon. Like clicking on anything other than those UCs shouldn't interfere with the onFocused styles of currently focus UC. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Try asking simple questions and avoid terms like "screen". Use "window" or "control" instead. Also, please provide code snippets to make your problem easier to understand and show what you try to accomplish. That question is kind of hard to read. Creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) often helps yourself and the answerers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a new focus scope for the context which should have an independent focus management, with the help of the `FocusManager`:

```
<MyUserControl FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" />
```